# php: using mysqli with odbc connections

Tags: php, odbc, mysqli

i was wondering if it would be possible using the mysqli interface for accessing odbc connections? i'm currently accessing an ms access database via odbc driver and php but it's a bit inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use mysqli to access MS Access, the mysql improved extension only talks to the mysql client library either directly or via mysqlnd native driver. You could use PDO to access both but you will lose some functionality over mysqli.